INS-20802 Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed. in Oracle19C
While Installing the Oracle 19C, Faced an Issue with DBCA where the following error is given
In the 4th Line of the Log, DBEXPRESS is selected but there is no port no. is taken by the installer.. Why is that?
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] Executing DBCA
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] Command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c call C:\Oracle\product\19.3.0\dbhome\bin\dbca.bat -progress_only -createDatabase -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -sid ORCL -gdbName ORCL.IN-V-OPCD167 -**emConfiguration DBEXPRESS** -storageType FS -datafileDestination C:\Oracle\oradata -datafileJarLocation C:\Oracle\product\19.3.0\dbhome/assistants/dbca/templates -characterset AL32UTF8 -obfuscatedPasswords false -recoveryAreaDestination NONE -automaticMemoryManagement false -totalMemory 6553 -maskPasswords false -ignorePrereqFailure -skipEnforcePasswordComplexityCheck true -oui_internal 
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] ... GenericInternalPlugIn.handleProcess() entered.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] ... GenericInternalPlugIn: getting configAssistantParmas.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] ... GenericInternalPlugIn: checking secretArguments.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:13 PM] ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] [WARNING] [INS-08101] Unexpected error while executing the action at state: 'ManagementOptions'
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Skipping line: [WARNING] [INS-08101] Unexpected error while executing the action at state: 'ManagementOptions'
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM]    CAUSE: No additional information available.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Skipping line:    CAUSE: No additional information available.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM]    ACTION: Contact Oracle Support Services or refer to the software manual.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Skipping line:    ACTION: Contact Oracle Support Services or refer to the software manual.
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM]    SUMMARY:
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Skipping line:    SUMMARY:
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM]        - java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Skipping line:        - java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Completed Plugin named: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant
INFO:  [20 Aug, 2024 6:19:26 PM] Setup completed with overall status as Failed`

